# unable to call json nested object image properties

Tags: json

in my case i am unable to call properties from a nested image object properties.below is my code. I have to print price and image title on html page. I really dont knw where i am wrong. Any help will be helpful.

how i called data :

```
     const singerDetails = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    for (let i = 0; i < singerDetails.abc.length;enter code here i++) {
      console.log(singerDetails.abc[i].price);
    }
```

but what should i do for image object ? i tried

```
 console.log(singerDetails.abc[i].image.title);   but it gives error ..
```

```
    Json File :
    {
    "abc": [
          {
             "price": 9,
             "tea": "black",
```

`},
      {
         "image": {
           "alt": "hi i m alt",
            "title": "i am tittle",
         },
         "price": 10,
        "tea": "green",
         },
       {
         "price": 19,
         "tea": "black",

      },
      {
         "image": {
           "alt": "hi i m alt2",
            "title": "i am tittle2",
         },
         "price": 10,
        "tea": "green",
         }
 ]  
}`

Answer (score 0):

delete last comma in each of obj properties/

[JS Bin code here](https://jsbin.com/reripowuye/edit?js,console)

```
{"price": 19,"tea": "black"}
```

...

Comment: `const singerDetails = JSON.parse(file);
    for (let i = 0; i < singerDetails.abc.length; i++) {
        if(singerDetails.abc[i].image) {
   console.log(singerDetails.abc[i].image.title);
  }
 }`